# Remove escape characters from JSON string pulled from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, wpdb, json

I'm pulling rows that contain JSON content from a DB like this:

```
<?php

    //get the data from the database
    global $wpdb;
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $username     = $current_user->user_login;
    $rowResults = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT username, myJson FROM jsonData WHERE username = '$username'" ); 

 ?>
```

Then I'm trying to deconstruct the JSON back into a javascript object:

```
                      <?php echo $i ?>
                      <?php echo $result->username; ?>
                      <script>

                      let itemFromDB = <?php echo $result->myJson; ?>;

                      let parsedItem = JSON.parse(itemFromDB);

                      doSomething(parsedItem); //use the js object

                      </script>


                      <?php $i++ ?>

                      <br>

                    <?php } ?>
```

The problem is that itemFromDB will contain a string that has escape characters everywhere like this:

```
{\"someData\":\"qwe\",\"moreData\":\"2\",\"tags\":\"dffdf\",\"evenMore\":\"30\",\"anotherOne\":\"1\",\"moreandmore\":[{\"something\":\"w\",\"amount\":\"1};
```

I tried to write:

```
let itemFromDB = <?php echo json_decode($result->myJson); ?>;
```

But that just resulted in an empty string.

How can I remove the escape characters and convert my query result into a javascript object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to decode JSON string to use in the JS code, so something like

```
let parsedItem = <?php echo stripslashes($result->myJson); ?>;
```

Note that you will get JSON object, so no need to call JSON.parse there. I added stripslashes to remove extra \" from json string loaded from database.

Comment: With that I'm getting this error: Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: just drop json_decode - what was I thinking :D Keep stripslashes - that will remove slashes and just echo it. Your parsed item will be JSON object (so no need to parse it);

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!